# LCD Clock Millis Code Issue

Tags: lcd, millis

I am trying to create a clock on an LCD when I upload the code below, all it displays is a very rapidly flashing 0:00 PM. Please help. This is my first time using Millis.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>   //includes LCD display library in sketch
LiquidCrystal lcd(27,26,25,24,23,22);   //determines pins of the LCD display
int seconds = 0;    //generates integer storing seconds
int minutes = 0;    //generates integer storing and showing minutes
int hours = 12;      //generates integer storing hours in 24 hour mode
int displayHours;      //generates integer displaying hours in 12 hour mode
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;   //creates a variable to store the amount of milliseconds since last update
const long interval = 1000;    //generates integer to find 1 second interval


void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);  //determines size of the LCD display
}

void loop()   //runs code repeatedly
{
  updateSeconds();   //runs the updateSeconds function
  clockShown();   //runs the clockShown function
  clockConversion();    //runs the clockConversion function
}


void updateSeconds()   //check to see if it's time to update the seconds integer
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();  //generates the number of milliseconds program has been running
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) 
    {
      previousMillis = currentMillis; //updates the last time seconds was updated
      seconds = seconds ++;   //adds a second to the counter
   }
}


void clockShown()   //displays the time on an LCD display
{
  lcd.clear();   //resets screen on LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);    //sets the place to start writing at the top left corner of the LCD
  lcd.print(displayHours);  //displays hours
  lcd.print(":");   //displays colon
  if(minutes <= 9)  //if the minute is 1 digit
  {
    lcd.print("0"); //displays 0
  }
  lcd.print(minutes);  //displays minutes
  if(hours < 12)lcd.print(" AM");  //displays AM in the morning
  if(hours >= 12)lcd.print(" PM");   //displays PM at night
}

void clockConversion()  //runs math to convert seconds minutes and hours
{
  if(seconds == 60) //when seconds is 60
  { 
    seconds = 0;  //set seconds back to 0
    minutes = minutes ++;  //and add a minute
  } 
  if(minutes == 60) //when minutes is 60
  { 
    minutes = 0; //set minutes back to 0
    displayHours = displayHours ++; //and add an hour
    hours = hours ++; //and keep track of AM PM
  } 
  if(displayHours == 13)  //if the hour being displayed is 13
  { 
    displayHours = 1; //make it 1 instead
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
seconds = seconds ++;   //adds a second to the counter
```

This command grabs the value of `seconds`, increments the value of `seconds`, and then assigns the previously grabbed value to `seconds`. Or rather, it does nothing to change the value of `seconds`.

This mistake is repeated for `minutes`, `hours`, and `displayHours` in the `clockConversion()` function.

*Instead*

```
seconds++;
```

That was the main problem. The other problems described below are just for efficiency.

**Problem 2**

```
void loop()   //runs code repeatedly
{
  updateSeconds();   //runs the updateSeconds function
  clockShown();   //runs the clockShown function
  clockConversion();    //runs the clockConversion function
}
```

Why would you display the clock with `clockShown()` *before* you run `clockConversion()` to nice-up the minute and hour carry-over? Since you are running both `clockShown()` and `clockConversion()` at a high frequency, it doesn't matter much, but from a program flow point of view, I think it makes more sense to do the conversion before you display the values.

**Problem 3**

You are only updating `seconds` every 1000 milliseconds, using the `millis()` function. This is good.

However, nothing at all changes during the 1000 milliseconds between the incrementing of `seconds`. Why not pull the `millis()` parts into `loop()` and call all 3 functions only once per second?

```
void loop()   //runs code repeatedly
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();  //generates the number of milliseconds program has been running
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= waittime) 
  {
    previousMillis = currentMillis; //updates the last time seconds was updated

    updateSeconds();   //runs the updateSeconds function
    clockConversion();    //runs the clockConversion function
    clockShown();   //runs the clockShown function
  }
}
```